# Cache static content for speed up Pages performance IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, iis, iis-8

My application is in mvc4. When I render page its take too much time. I've checked in network tab its taking too much time for rendering `.js` files.

Can any one guide me how to do cache for static folder in iis 8.5 or any thing i can do in web.config after that i increase performance of my website and their pages.

It's taking time 10-20 seconds to render page. Here is the image of time.

All `js` files are in script folder, is their any method to cache whole folder?
[image]

Comment: Do you know about Bundling and Minification? [Read here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve request load time using bundling.

Add your bundle class to `App_Start` folder, and all `Js` file like following.

```
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/trans/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap_min.css",
              "~/Content/Theme/Css/style.css",
            ));
            bundles.Add(new JsBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.js",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.js"));
    }

   }
}
```

Register your bundle to `Global.asax` file.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

And use that js bundle on view page(`_Layout.cshtml`)

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/JsBundle")
```

Same way you can also bundle `CSS` files.

Hope this will help you!